can i get a solution for an error occurred during creating react app using create-react-app?
when i tried to create a react app using create-react-app im faced with error and unable to create the app.
and the error is....
npm error code EAI_AGAIN

npm error syscall getaddrinfo

npm error errno EAI_AGAIN

npm error request to https://registry.npmjs.org/create-react-app failed, reason: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN proxy.example.com

i tried to reinstall node js and clear npm cache but nothing worked.

It seems you could be using a misconfigured proxy. npm config delete proxy; npm config delete https-proxy

thank youb, but still not worked

probably a system setting? it is weird you get that proxy.example.com in the error

The EAI_AGAIN blunders is normally related to DNS research failures. Here are some steps to solve it:
Check Internet Connection: Ensure you have a strong connection.
Change DNS Provider: Switch to Google DNS (8.8.8.Eight, eight.Eight.4.4) or Cloudflare DNS (1.1.1.1).
Clear DNS Cache:
Windows: ipconfig /flushdns
macOS: sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder
Check Proxy Settings:
Remove proxy settings: npm config delete proxy and npm config delete https-proxy
Try a Different Network: Connect to a exclusive network.
Update npm: npm install -g npm
Use Yarn:
Install Yarn: npm set up -g yarn
Create React app: yarn create react-app my-app
Use npx: npx create-react-app my-app --use-npm
These steps must help you resolve the EAI_AGAIN error and create your React app.


According to [the] Microsoft Docs EAI_AGAIN error code translate to temporary failure in name resolution, that is a DNS issue.

Source
The most likely issue is that you are on a slow network that causes NPM to timeout. Try this on a different network if you can. Additional turn off any VPN you may be using.
The are a few other things you can try:
Fix dns issue with NPM
Run:
npm config rm proxy 
npm config rm https-proxy 

This will remove the NPM proxy.
Flush your dns

DNS flushing is the process of clearing the Domain Name System (DNS) cache on your device. Most devices store records retrieved from DNS servers in their cache to avoid repeat queries in the future.

Source
On macOS

Open the terminal
Run sudo dscacheutil -flushcache; sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder

On Windows

Open CMD as an adminstrator
Run ipconfig /flushdns

On Linux

Open the terminal
Run sudo lsof -i :53 -S

